# how to show the product price in template with currency (WHMCS)

Tags: php, smarty, whmcs, whmcs-invoice-template

I need, when user currency change this time automatically price change the related with the active current.

```
<h4 class="h5">Starting At<strong>
{if  $currency=2 } // currency id = 2//
 Rs 1.19                                        
 {else}
 $ 1.19
{/if}
<small>/m</small></strong></h4>
```

I try this code. but not work. :(
please help me

Comment: In WHMCS you can add multiple currency, and set product price for each currency. Is that what you want?

Comment: i want, when current currency = us, us currency id=1, this time show this currency price. like-> <h4 class="h5">Starting At<strong>
{if  $currency=1 } // current currency id = 1//
 $1.19                                        
 {else}
 Rs. 1.19
{/if}
<small>/m</small></strong></h4>

Comment: how to called current currency, and display current currency price.

Comment: which tpl file you're editing?

Comment: i created a new home page tpl file. this file called call current currency and show price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WHMCS doesn't load current currency on all pages, i think only cart pages.

So you need to add a currency selection form to allow client to switch between currencies.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="currency_sel">Currency:</label>
    <select name="currency" id="currency_sel" class="form-control" onchange="submit();">
        <option value="1" {if $smarty.post.currency eq '1'}selected{/if}>$</option>
        <option value="2" {if $smarty.post.currency eq '2'}selected{/if}>Rs</option>
    </select>   

</form>
```

The selected currency will be available with the variable `$smarty.post.currency` Update your code as following:

```
<h4 class="h5">Starting At<strong>
{if  $smarty.post.currency eq '2' } 
 Rs 1.19                                        
 {else}
 $ 1.19
{/if}
<small>/m</small></strong></h4>
```

Comment: can you tell, how to currency automatically change using user active country code?

Comment: that's the problem, but can i use country ip address then it is work?

Comment: Check this module, it might help: https://www.modulesgarden.com/products/whmcs/geolocation-hook

Answer (score -1):

Use this 100% working

```
 {if  $activeCurrency.id > 1 }
    $0.60
    {else}
    ₹45
    {/if}
```